# Java - set rotation by setting positions of the points for drawing the faces for a cube

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, minecraft, cube

I'm doing this in minecraft using a tesselator.... but that doesn't matter.

Bacisally I'm drawing a cube using vertexes..
Every face has 4 position points.

First look at the world coordinates. I add positions of to the vertexes/faces in this order: DCBA.. you'll get that later..(hopefully)

[image: world coords in MC]

Based on that, this is how I draw the cube:

```
public void renderParticles(World w, float x, float y, float z, Tesselator t)
{//**THIS IS AN EXAMPLE METHOD**
int scale = 1;
Random r;

int rotX = r.NextInt(10);
int rotY = r.NextInt(10);
int rotZ = r.NextInt(10);

//front face
     t.addVertex(x,        y,        z);
     t.addVertex(x,        y + scale,z);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y + scale,z);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y,        z);

//left face (I might have the Z coords wrong but that doesnt matter right now - basically the other direction)
     t.addVertex(x,          y,        z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x,          y + scale,z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x,          y + scale,z);
     t.addVertex(x,          y,        z);

//back face
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y,        z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y + scale,z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x,        y + scale,z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x,        y,        z + scale);

//right face
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y,        z);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y + scale,z);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y + scale,z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y,        z + scale);

//top face
     t.addVertex(x,        y + scale,z);
     t.addVertex(x,        y + scale,z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y + scale,z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y + scale,z);

//bottom face
     t.addVertex(x,        y,        z + scale);
     t.addVertex(x,        y,        z);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y,        z);
     t.addVertex(x + scale,y,        z + scale);
}
```

When this cube spawns/draws, I want it to be already randomly rotated.

I don't know such hardcore math...

**Why am I not posting this on minecraftforge forums?**

*-The mod that this code is in, is a coremod(they do not support them there)*

*-Actually already sked them, they told me to first make it a normal mod.*

.

Any ideas how I could possibly rotate this cube then(I hope I wrote all the cube faces correctly :D)?

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I'm using right now because I updated it to mc version 1.10:

```
/**
 * Renders the particle
 */
public void renderParticle(VertexBuffer worldRendererIn, Entity entityIn, float partialTicks, float rotationX,
        float rotationZ, float rotationYZ, float rotationXY, float rotationXZ) {
    float f = ((float) this.particleTextureIndexX + this.particleTextureJitterX / 4.0F) / 16.0F;
    float f1 = f + 0.015609375F;
    float f2 = ((float) this.particleTextureIndexY + this.particleTextureJitterY / 4.0F) / 16.0F;
    float f3 = f2 + 0.015609375F;
    float f4 = 0.1F * this.particleScale;

    if (this.particleTexture != null) {
        f = this.particleTexture.getInterpolatedU((double) (this.particleTextureJitterX / 4.0F * 16.0F));
        f1 = this.particleTexture.getInterpolatedU((double) ((this.particleTextureJitterX + 1.0F) / 4.0F * 16.0F));
        f2 = this.particleTexture.getInterpolatedV((double) (this.particleTextureJitterY / 4.0F * 16.0F));
        f3 = this.particleTexture.getInterpolatedV((double) ((this.particleTextureJitterY + 1.0F) / 4.0F * 16.0F));
    }

    float f5 = (float) (this.prevPosX + (this.posX - this.prevPosX) * (double) partialTicks - interpPosX);
    float f6 = (float) (this.prevPosY + (this.posY - this.prevPosY) * (double) partialTicks - interpPosY);
    float f7 = (float) (this.prevPosZ + (this.posZ - this.prevPosZ) * (double) partialTicks - interpPosZ);

    int i = this.getBrightnessForRender(partialTicks);
    int j = i >> 16 & 65535;
    int k = i & 65535;

    if (Minecraft.isFancyGraphicsEnabled() == true) {
        if (spawned == false) {
            this.particleRed *= 1.35F;
            this.particleGreen *= 1.35F;
            this.particleBlue *= 1.35F;

            spawned = true;
        }

        // front
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6, f7 + f4).tex((double) f, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6 + f4, f7 + f4).tex((double) f, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6 + f4, f7 + f4).tex((double) f1, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6, f7 + f4).tex((double) f1, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();

        // back
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6, f7).tex((double) f1, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();

        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6 + f4, f7).tex((double) f1, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        // done
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6 + f4, f7).tex((double) f, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();

        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6, f7).tex((double) f, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();

        // left
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6, f7 + f4).tex((double) f1, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6 + f4, f7 + f4).tex((double) f, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6 + f4, f7).tex((double) f, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6, f7).tex((double) f1, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();

        // right
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6, f7).tex((double) f, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6 + f4, f7).tex((double) f1, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6 + f4, f7 + f4).tex((double) f1, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6, f7 + f4).tex((double) f, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();

        // top
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6 + f4, f7).tex((double) f1, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6 + f4, f7 + f4).tex((double) f1, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6 + f4, f7 + f4).tex((double) f, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6 + f4, f7).tex((double) f, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();

        // bottom
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6, f7 + f4).tex((double) f, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6, f7).tex((double) f, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6, f7).tex((double) f1, (double) f3)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
        worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6, f7 + f4).tex((double) f1, (double) f2)
                .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
                .endVertex();
    } else {
        worldRendererIn
                .pos((f5 - rotationX * f4 - rotationXY * f4), (double) (f6 - rotationZ * f4),
                        (double) (f7 - rotationYZ * f4 - rotationXZ * f4))
                .tex((double) f, (double) f3).color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, 1.0F)
                .lightmap(j, k).endVertex();
        worldRendererIn
                .pos((double) (f5 - rotationX * f4 + rotationXY * f4), (double) (f6 + rotationZ * f4),
                        (double) (f7 - rotationYZ * f4 + rotationXZ * f4))
                .tex((double) f, (double) f2).color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, 1.0F)
                .lightmap(j, k).endVertex();
        worldRendererIn
                .pos((double) (f5 + rotationX * f4 + rotationXY * f4), (double) (f6 + rotationZ * f4),
                        (double) (f7 + rotationYZ * f4 + rotationXZ * f4))
                .tex((double) f1, (double) f2).color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, 1.0F)
                .lightmap(j, k).endVertex();
        worldRendererIn
                .pos((double) (f5 + rotationX * f4 - rotationXY * f4), (double) (f6 - rotationZ * f4),
                        (double) (f7 + rotationYZ * f4 - rotationXZ * f4))
                .tex((double) f1, (double) f3).color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, 1.0F)
                .lightmap(j, k).endVertex();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at rotation matrices. http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Answer (score 1):

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();
float rotateAxis = 1.0f;
float stableAxis = 0.0f;

int degreesPitch = (1+random.nextInt(4))*90;
int degreesRoll = (1+random.nextInt(4))*90;
int degreesYaw = (1+random.nextInt(4))*90;

GL11.glRotate(degreesRoll , stableAxis ,stableAxis ,rotateAxis );
GL11.glRotate(degreesYaw , stableAxis ,rotateAxis ,stableAxis );
GL11.glRotate(degreesPitch ,rotateAxis ,stableAxis ,stableAxis );
//Your tessellator code
tessellator.draw();
GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

And don't do `tessellator.addVertex` but do `tessellator.addVertexWithUV(vertexX, vertexY, vertexY, U,V)` so you have textured vertices.

and don't forget to call `tessellator.draw()` at the end.

usefull to know yaw, pitch and roll http://howthingsfly.si.edu/flight-dynamics/roll-pitch-and-yaw

**EDIT**

Okay, your code like this,this is a complete quad.

```
    // front
    worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6, f7 + f4).tex((double) f, (double) f2)
            .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
            .endVertex();
    worldRendererIn.pos(f5 + f4, f6 + f4, f7 + f4).tex((double) f, (double) f3)
            .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
            .endVertex();
    worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6 + f4, f7 + f4).tex((double) f1, (double) f3)
            .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
            .endVertex();
    worldRendererIn.pos(f5, f6, f7 + f4).tex((double) f1, (double) f2)
            .color(this.particleRed, this.particleGreen, this.particleBlue, this.particleAlpha).lightmap(j, k)
            .endVertex();
```

To draw a quad you need to set your world renderer mode

```
   //OpenGL enable/blend functions/etc... here
   // for example GL11.glScalef(scale, scale, scale);

   worldrenderer.begin(7, DefaultVertexFormats.POSITION_TEX_COLOR_NORMAL);

   // your vertex defining code
   // your vertex defining code
   // your vertex defining code

    worldRendererIn.normal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);


   tessellator.draw();
   // OPENGL disable code here
```

That last line, tesselator.draw() will make sure it'll get drawn to screen, that the vertex buffer is flushed into a single displaylist.

Comment: ok.. while nobody was answering this post, I updated it to 1.10 so it uses vertexbuffer instead of a tessellator.. I tried using VertexBufferRef.finishDrawing().. that crashes.. I'll try it without that line..

Comment: Vertexbuffer.finish is the same as worldrenderer.finish. its ends all drawing. Take a look at the obj renderer in forge src

Comment: Im gonna edit my answer a bit later. Dont have the time atm. Stay tuned

Comment: It crashes because it is already rendering as it says... (crashes on the line with worldRendererIn.begin();)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122864/discussion-between-tom-lenc-and-tschallacka).